# Clear Redux Persist store using redux-reset

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I have a action for logout like this. I'm using the [redux-reset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-reset).

```
export const logoutAction = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'RESET'
    });
  };
};
```

It's not resetting, can anyone please help me?

And store i have configured like this

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import reduxReset from 'redux-reset'

    import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage
    };

    const enHanceCreateStore = compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
      reduxReset()
    )(createStore);

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

    export const store = enHanceCreateStore(persistedReducer);
    export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```